# Hexo markdown + bulma css

Tags: css, bulma, hexo

I am building static blog site with Hexo.

Now I want to use Bulma to make design easy.

But I wonder how I can call class name from markdown.

If markdown’s # or ## automatically link to Bulma’s class ‘title’ it would be nice.

Comment: I would like to have Any idea to make it happen

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether the following answer will work as I haven't tried it. But it will give you a good starting point.

First replace the default markdown renderer engine (marked) with `hexo-renderer-markdown-it` [Link](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-renderer-markdown-it)

```
npm un hexo-renderer-marked --save
npm i hexo-renderer-markdown-it --save
```

Then add the following in `_config.yml`

```
markdown: 'default'
```

For more infomation on values of markdown refer [Simple Configuration](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-renderer-markdown-it/wiki/Simple-Configuration) page.

We can add more options to the `_config.yml` file.

All options along with explanations can be found [Advanced Configuration](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-renderer-markdown-it/wiki/Advanced-Configuration) page

**Example Config**

```
# Markdown-it config
## Docs: https://github.com/celsomiranda/hexo-renderer-markdown-it/wiki
markdown:
  render:
    html: true
    xhtmlOut: false
    breaks: true
    linkify: true
    typographer: true
    quotes: '“”‘’'
  plugins:
    - markdown-it-abbr
    - markdown-it-footnote
    - markdown-it-ins
    - markdown-it-sub
    - markdown-it-sup
    - markdown-it-attrs
  anchors:
    level: 2
    collisionSuffix: 'v'
    permalink: true
    permalinkClass: header-anchor
    permalinkSymbol: ¶
```

The option which we are interested is the **plugin** option.

After some research, I found a plugin [markdown-it-attrs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-attrs) that can add class attribute as well as other attributes that we normally add, to markdown components

Example input:

```
# header {.style-me}
paragraph {data-toggle=modal}
```

Output:

```
<h1 class="style-me">header</h1>
<p data-toggle="modal">paragraph</p>
```

Works with inline elements too:

```
paragraph *style me*{.red} more text
```

Output:

```
<p>paragraph <em class="red">style me</em> more text</p>
```

More examples on plugin [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-attrs)

Add the plugin name in the plugin section of the `_config.yml` file